# Logging packet sent time by physical layer

Tags: unetstack

From the sender node i am sending packet by command in simulation script:
**router << new DatagramReq(to: 1, data:[1,1,1,1], protocol:Protocol.DATA);** 
I want to know, how to log the Datagram sent time by Physical layer of the sender in log-0.txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the log level of the agent to FINE should log all messages sent by that agent. The logger name for each agent follows the class name of the agent, by convention. If you do a `ps`, you'll see the class names of the agents:

```
> ps
remote: org.arl.unet.remote.RemoteControl - IDLE
rdp: org.arl.unet.net.RouteDiscoveryProtocol - IDLE
ranging: org.arl.unet.phy.Ranging - IDLE
uwlink: org.arl.unet.link.ReliableLink - IDLE
node: org.arl.unet.nodeinfo.NodeInfo - IDLE
phy: org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem - IDLE
arp: org.arl.unet.addr.AddressResolution - IDLE
transport: org.arl.unet.transport.SWTransport - IDLE
router: org.arl.unet.net.Router - IDLE
mac: org.arl.unet.mac.CSMA - IDLE
```

You can see that the `phy` agent class is `org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem`, if you're running a simulator. You can set the log level of the simulation classes to INFO:

```
> logLevel 'org.arl.unet.sim', FINE
```

Now, the logs will show the messages (and their corresponding times). Example:

```
1567801752688|FINE|org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/A@47:handleTxFrameReq|TxFrameReq:REQUEST[type:DATA to:1 (4 bytes)] Data:
    01010101
1567801752741|FINE|org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/A@47:sendTxFrameNtf|TxFrameNtf:INFORM[type:DATA txTime:753410296]
1567801753392|FINE|org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/B@63:sendRxFrameStartNtf|RxFrameStartNtf:INFORM[type:DATA rxTime:3515132027]
1567801754095|FINE|org.arl.unet.sim.HalfDuplexModem/B@63:sendRxFrameNtf|RxFrameNtf:INFORM[type:DATA from:232 to:1 rxTime:3515132027 (4 bytes)] Data:
    01010101
```